# query when number of conditions is not defined

Tags: asp.net, linq

How can I create a query when the number of conditions is chosen by the user?

For example: I have a Customer table in my database, user can select 1 or many cities and the screen will display customers whose city is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Contains`:

```
int[] selectedCities = {1,2,3};

var query = db.Customer.Where(c => selectedCities.Contains(c.CityId));
```